# Javascript Checking array value always return -1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following route in my AngularJS app, where I save permission level for each route in an array as shown in the code below. Then I check if the current logged in user has permission level matching that of the route to be loaded, using the code below, but I always get result -1 even if the logged user permission is matching one of those in the plevel array. Can someone please check my code and tell me what exactly I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

```
       $routeProvider.when('/clients/new-invoice', 
        {     templateUrl: 'templates/new-invoice.html', 
              controller: 'InvoicesController',
              title: 'New Invoice',
              data: {
                 auth: true,
                 plevel: [5, 6, 8] 
              }                
        });


 $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

      var CContent = $.cookie('UCookie');

      console.log('User - permission match : ' + $.inArray(CContent, next.data. plevel) );  
  });
```

Comment: I'm curious, what browsers do you have to support?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum All popular browsers

Comment: That did not answer my question, but meh.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, does this answer your question?

Comment: Do you need to support IE8?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes

Comment: What do you get when you log the value of `CContent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.inArray` uses strict equality and you are comparing a string to ints which are not strictly equal (`5 === "5" //returns false`) thus the -1. You should first convert `CContent` to an int like this:

`CContent = parseInt($.cookie('UCookie'), 10);`